# ReactorNettyWebSocketClient consume from multiple websocket endpoints

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-websocket

I have couple of simple websocket servers endpoints running known as /enpoint1 and /endpoint2. I am using ReactorNettyWebSocketClient to establish a client and receive the stream of messages from both the endpoints. I want to do that simultaneously from the both the endpoints. This is what I have come up with --

```
WebSocketClient quotesClient = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();
        WebSocketClient instrumentClient = new ReactorNettyWebSocketClient();

        quotesClient.execute(
                URI.create("ws://localhost:8080/endpoint1"),
                session -> session.receive()
                        .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                        .log()
                        .then())
                .block();

        instrumentClient.execute(
                URI.create("ws://localhost:8080/endpoint2"),
                session -> session.receive()
                        .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                        .log()
                        .then())
                .block();
```

Problem is it only reads messages from the first endpoint and skips the second one. I have use SpringBoot application to setup the server etc. Do I need to define them in separate classes or any specific configuration needed to do the same ?